# Get a list of ids from documents where children only know about their parents

Tags: javascript, json, browser

so I have this data structure coming out from CouchDB.

```
[
 {
   id: '1',
   type: 'bot',
 },
 {
   id: '2',
   type: 'conversation',
   owner: '1', // bot id 1
 },
 {
   id: '3',
   type: 'message',
   owner: '2', // conversation id 2
 },
 {
   id: '4',
   type: 'message',
   owner: '2', // conversation id 2
 },
 {
   id: '5',
   type: 'conversation',
   owner: '1', // bot id 1
 },
 {
   id: '6',
   type: 'bot',
 },
 {
   id: '7',
   type: 'conversation',
   owner: '6', // bot id 6
 },
 {...}
]
```

I'm trying to get a list of ids starting a potential parent. The parent id could be a conversation id (which owns messages) but also a bot id (which owns conversation and messages).

So based on the data above and if I provide the id `1` (which is a bot in this case) the expected result would be `[2, 3, 4, 5]`.

I'm trying to get this done using vanilla JS. I was avoiding recursion because of the lack of tail call optimization in browsers.

Thank you!

Comment: what about `'7'`?

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry that was a typo, I've fixed it. `7` belongs to `6`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a two pass approach (with a later used recursion). First collect and assign all children to their parents and then get all children.

```js
function getChildren(array, id) {
    function iter(id) {
        result.push(id);
        (children[id] || []).forEach(iter);
    }

    var children = Object.create(null),
        result = [];

    array.forEach(function (o) {
        if ('owner' in o) {
            children[o.owner] = children[o.owner] || [];
            children[o.owner].push(o.id);
        }
    }),
    iter(id);
    return result.slice(1); // without starting id
}

var data = [{ id: '1', type: 'bot' }, { id: '2', type: 'conversation', owner: '1' }, { id: '3', type: 'message', owner: '2' }, { id: '4', type: 'message', owner: '2' }, { id: '5', type: 'conversation', owner: '1' }, { id: '6', type: 'bot' }, { id: '7', type: 'conversation', owner: '6' }];

console.log(getChildren(data, '1'));
```